# Adf selectonechoice adding item

Tags: jsp, jsf, oracle-adf

I have list in managedbean from webservice.

> List itResKeys = new ArrayList<>();

1- How to be bind this list with selectonechoice component?

2- How to add selected from jsf page to managedbean

Comment: There is an example how to bind your selectOneChoice to customList : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44498782/1752867

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of SelectItem Objects .
Like`List<SelectItem> myList = new ArrayList<>();` . Bind this list to `<af:selectItems>` in select one Choice. retreiving values from here you can google.

-Sid